# Failed to infer CIDR network for mon ip

Tags: ceph

I follow the [instructions](https://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/cephadm/install/) to bootstrap a new Ceph (I'm new to Ceph) cluster.
I got the following error:

```sh
sudo cephadm bootstrap --mon-ip <mon-ip>

INFO:cephadm:Verifying podman|docker is present...
INFO:cephadm:Verifying lvm2 is present...
INFO:cephadm:Verifying time synchronization is in place...
INFO:cephadm:Unit systemd-timesyncd.service is enabled and running
INFO:cephadm:Repeating the final host check...
INFO:cephadm:podman|docker (/usr/bin/podman) is present
INFO:cephadm:systemctl is present
INFO:cephadm:lvcreate is present
INFO:cephadm:Unit systemd-timesyncd.service is enabled and running
INFO:cephadm:Host looks OK
INFO:root:Cluster fsid: e08484be-72c1-11ea-a13e-0050563f093a
INFO:cephadm:Verifying IP *<mon-ip>* port 3300 ...
INFO:cephadm:Verifying IP *<mon-ip>* port 6789 ...
ERROR: Failed to infer CIDR network for mon ip *<mon-ip>*; pass --skip-mon-network to configure it later
```

What does it mean ? How to fix it ?

Comment: I am still struggling with this problem. How can the probelm: ERROR: Failed to infer CIDR network for mon ip ....  ?

Answer (score 0):

cephadm is still fairly new. I've tracked a few days ago in:

https://tracker.ceph.com/issues/44828

Please run

```
ceph config set mon public_network <mon_network>
```

after bootstrap finished.

Comment: Hi, I know you created this issue for me. I posted it here before talking to you on IRC #ceph  ) Anyway, I'm blocked down the road with ssh config ;)

Answer (score -2):

Is this the exact command you ran?

```
sudo cephadm bootstrap --mon-ip *<mon-ip>*
```

If so you actually need to replace `*<mon-ip>*` with the actual IP address that you want the monitor daemon to listen on.

For future reference, on that page, any command you see that has a variable surrounded by asterisks is something you would need to replace with an address/host/hostname etc. that applies to your environment.

Comment: No, it was not a placeholder, it was my actual IP address. I would doubt it would produce this error with a placeholder :)